# Custom Access Denied Page for Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-form, access-denied

I was wondering if there exists a way to customize the Out of the Box Access Denied page, or Redirect it to custom access denied page in SharePoint Online. So far I haven't found a way, and Microsoft community only has one such question, where the answers are that Redirecting or having a custom Access Denied page is not possible in SharePoint online. Is this confirmed or is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible in SharePoint Online. There are multiple threads including one where a Microsoft employee also stated it wasn't possible:

[SharePoint Online: How to have Custom access denined page in SharePoint Online?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/417634/sharepoint-online-how-to-have-custom-access-denine.html)

[Customize out of the box access denied page on SharePoint online](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/customize-out-of-the-box-access-denied-page-on-sharepoint-online/m-p/678148)

There is also a feedback item on the Microsoft Feedback portal for it. I would recommend voting for it, if you would like to see this functionality:

[Allow administrators to create a custom Access Denied message](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/8fd510e1-de1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8945)