# How to add custom message on SharePoint Online AccessDenied.aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-online, application-pages

I want to add custom message on SharePoint online out of box Access Denied page (_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx).

Is it possible in any way ? If yes, please highlight.

Eg., like below custom text I want to add.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A very similar question has been answered recently (September 2022):

[Custom Access Denied Page for Sharepoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/303969/91738)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Callum Crowley, per my knowledge, there is no out of the box option to custom or redirect the Access Denied page in the SharePoint online.

Update:

Go to Site permissions -> Change how members can share -> Access requests -> Add a custom message to the request access page.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check.